# Orbeon Forms: Determine Form URL when Form Opens

Tags: orbeon

We need to determine which environment the form is being generated from via the form URL.

We need this as the form has URLs that call other apps, and these apps can be test, QA or production apps. So, as an example, a form in a test environment needs to call a 3rd party app URL which is also in a test environment:

OrbeonFormTestSystem - 3rdPartyAppTestSystem
OrbeonFormQualitySystem - 3rdPartyAppQualitySystem
OrbeonFormProductionSystem - 3rdPartyAppProductionSystem

So to do this we need to interrogate the form URL to see which environment is being used. We can do this via the following JavaScript code:

```
var isProdEnv = window.location.host.includes("prod_indicator");
```

We then need to use the above result to hide/display the relevant 3rd party app URLs.

I tried using an action using:

```
<xf:action event="xforms-model-construct-done" type="javascript"> </xf:action>
```

but this code gets wiped out, and doesn't work with the control xPath to toggle the visibility.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

PeteA

Comment: Hi Pete, I have two questions: (1.) Where in the URL does the string `prod_indicator` appear? I'm asking to determine which XPath function would be most appropriate. (2.) Once you've determined which environment you are in, how will you use this information? You mentioned that you plan to use it "to hide/display the relevant 3rd party app URLs," but I'm unclear on what you mean by this. -Alex

Comment: Here is an adjusted URL to show the format:

https://COMPANY-SYST_ID.launchpad.cfapps..........formRunner-display?sap-ui-app-id-hint=saas_approuter_com.sap.df.form-runner

And we need to read the SYST_ID part of the URL to identify whether the system is test, quality or production.

We need to determine this data as soon as the form opens so that dependent controls can hide/show relevant test/quality/production URLs to open the correct app for our 3rd party GIS supplier.

Comment: The test code I'm currently using looks like this:

<xf:action event="xforms-model-construct-done" type="javascript"> 
 var isProductionSystem = ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue(ORBEON.fr.API.findControlsByName("ProductionSystem")[0]);
        var isPROD = window.location.host.includes("PROD");                    
 if (isPROD == true) { isProductionSystem = "True" } else { isProductionSystem = "False" }
        ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue(ORBEON.fr.API.findControlsByName("ProductionSystem")[0],isProductionSystem)                </xf:action>

Comment: In this test form, if you close Section 1 and open it again, then the value disappears:

https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/a419504f4bc57e2e8b5b68501de1c7017eb3bf5b

Is this a bug?

Comment: Got it, Pete. I think I understand what you're aiming for and have posted an answer below. -Alex

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against using JavaScript to determine the environment, as this approach allows a user to open the console and execute the instruction below with their own value for `isProductionSystem`, thereby causing the form to mistakenly believe it is in a different environment than its actual one.

```js
ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue(
    ORBEON.fr.API.findControlsByName(
        "ProductionSystem")[0],
        isProductionSystem
)
```

Instead, it is better to rely on a formula that runs on the server. One way is to look at the `Host` header. You could use a hidden control named `ProductionSystem` with the following Calculated Value formula:

```xml
contains(xxf:get-request-header('host'), 'PROD')
```

Then, in other formulas, you can use:

```xml
$ProductionSystem = 'true'
```

Comment: I tried the following in a Calculated Value Formula but it always returns a "false" value:   
contains(xxf:get-request-header('host'), 'PROD')   
So I tried the following and it returns a blank value:  
xxf:get-request-header('host')  
Maybe this is because our solution is an "offline" solution??

Comment: @PeteAtkin Ah, indeed, I can see how this wouldn't work if the form is offline. So, you're using the form within a mobile app, correct? If so, how do you select the environment to use? Is there a setting in the mobile app for this?